# SQL Server 2008 R2 / SSRS 2008: Service Level Report Creation

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am just beginning to learn SSRS and am only intermediate at SQL Server and I am trying to create a report in SSRS that calculates a total time under the following scenario:

1. Call Start [time]
2. Call Progress [time]
3. Call Progress [time]
4. Hold [time]
5. Call Progress [time]
6. Hold [time]
7. Call Progress [time]
8. Call End [time]

The data I am trying to get at: Step 8 - Step 1 - (step 5 - step 4) - (Step 7 minus step 6) so I can get a raw time of time spent on a call for a service level report.

Things to keep in mind:

- May or may not be a hold,
- May or may not be multiple holds,
- Two holds may be placed back to back.

If I were doing this in visual basic I would use an array and loop through it to grab my variables. No idea how to do this or if it's possible in SSRS or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Help? (if you need more info I am happy to provide)

Comment: Can you post your SQL data structure that is holding the steps?

Comment: for ease of response and keeping the solution simple, assume the values are stored in a single table, side by side. IE. Row 1 [GUID] [Call Entered],[8:00 am] Row 2 [GUID] [Call Progress],[8:01 am] where the times are the start of the next event in the call.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a SQL problem than an SSRS issue if you are trying to get a computed column.  My question is from your structure are these all points separate columns in SQL or rows?  If they are columns it is much easier.

It appears you are just taking away the start time from the End time then some arbitrary numbers for duration.  To perform the SQL operation I will give an example that self extracts in SQL Management Studio:

```
declare @Time1 time = '15:00', @Time2 time = '16:42', @DurationMinutes int = 34;

select 
    @Time1 as Time1
,   @Time2 as Time2

-- datediff gives you differences in an incremenet you specify between two values of date, time, or datetime
,   datediff(hour, @Time1, @Time2) as DifferenceInHours
,   datediff(second, @Time1, @Time2) as DifferenceInSeconds
,   datediff(minute, @Time1, @Time2) as DifferenceInMinutes

-- Dateadd can add or subtract an increment type and value from a point specified.  Be careful if you use ONLY TIME that you may go back a day and not notice it
,   dateadd(minute, - @DurationMinutes, @Time1) as Time


,   datediff(minute, @Time1, @Time2) - @DurationMinutes as TimeInMinutesLessDurationOfArbitraryTalkTime
```